# Repeating post curl request until answer is 200 in bash

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, user-data

I've got this script in the user-data of an ec2 linux. Is there a way to do a while to "loop" in this script so that it keeps doing the curl requests every 5 minutes until the requests return 200?

```
#!/bin/bash
      sed -i -e '/<Name>loadbalanceServerIP<\/Name>/,/<Value>/s/<Value>[^<]*/<Value>52.53.197.227/' /home/wowza/conf/Server.xml
      edge_ip=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4`
    curl --digest -u 'wowza:i-0fbfeb0718fab03b8' -X POST --header 'Accept:application/json; charset=utf-8' --header 'Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8' http://52.53.197.227:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/live/pushpublish/mapentries/letitoptier_source -d'
    {
      "restURI":          "http://52.53.197.227:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/live/pushpublish/mapentries/letitoptier_source",
      "serverName":       "_defaultServer_",
      "sourceStreamName": "letitoptier_source",
      "entryName":        "letitoptier_source_target",
      "profile":          "rtmp",
      "host":             "'$edge_ip'",
      "application":      "live",
      "userName":         "wowza",
      "password":         "i-0fbfeb0718fab03b8",
      "streamName":       "letitoptier_source"
    }'
    curl --digest -u 'wowza:i-0fbfeb0718fab03b8' -X POST --header 'Accept:application/json; charset=utf-8' --header 'Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8' http://52.53.197.227:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/live/pushpublish/mapentries/letitoptier_160p -d'
    {
      "restURI":          "http://52.53.197.227:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/live/pushpublish/mapentries/letitoptier_160p",
      "serverName":       "_defaultServer_",
      "sourceStreamName": "letitoptier_160p",
      "entryName":        "letitoptier_160p_target",
      "profile":          "rtmp",
      "host":             "'$edge_ip'",
      "application":      "live",
      "userName":         "wowza",
      "password":         "i-0fbfeb0718fab03b8",
      "streamName":       "letitoptier_160p"
    }'
```

How can I know if it ran and what result or message it returned?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are unsure whether the User Data script executed, log files are available at:

- Linux: `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`
- Windows: `C:\cfn`

Comment: Great thanks. Do you know how I could do a while to do a "loop" in this script so that it keeps requesting every 5 minutes until the curl requests are ok?